# SEO on Angularjs based website using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, shell, seo, ubuntu-14.04

I want my site to be crawlable, which is on AngularJS. I have decided to use phantomjs for the same and tried these 2 methods but not succeeded.

**Method 1:** I followed this [blog](http://lawsonry.com/2014/05/diy-angularjs-seo-with-phantomjs-the-easy-way/). I set up everything correctly when I make curl request on any page say

`curl "www.mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/path/to/page" > output.html`

i get the content for www.mywebsite.com/path/to/page in output.html file in which correct description and tags are present. I submitted the same url to google webmaster(correctly fetched and rendered) and submitted to index. Google indexed my page in few hours. but i am not getting my url's description and tags. Can you point what mistake I am doing.

attaching screenshot of one such url: **www.ketchupp.in/gurgaon/sohna-road**
 [image]

**Method2:** I followed this [blog](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html) also and tried to create snapshot for my page using command:

> ./make-snapshot.sh 'http://www.ketchupp.in/#/gurgaon/sohna-road'

I got snapshot of the page in /snapshot/gurgaon folder. and my rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1.html? [NC,L]
```

when I do

> curl 'www.ketchupp.in/?_escaped_fragment_=/gurgaon/sohna-road'

i am getting correct html snapshot, with correct tile, tags and description. But when I search it on google it is showing title and description and tags of home page. Can anyone help me in finding what might be the reason of the same.